# How can I check/upgrade Proguard version when using it in Eclipse for Android development?

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard

The documentation on this is extremely poor. I understand that ProGuard can be enabled by manually editing "default.properties" in the project's rot directory. And all the settings go into the "proguard.cfg" file in the same place, but I'd like to know which version of ProGuard is being used (I'm using Eclise Indigo). I would also like to be able to upgrade it to the latest versions whenever the are released. But I can't find any reference on how to do it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The ProGuard jar is located inside the Android SDK: android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar

You can print out its version number with

```
java -jar android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar
```

(with the proper path). If necessary, you can **replace the jar** (actually, the entire `proguard` subdirectory) with the latest version from the [download page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) at the official ProGuard site.

Comment: Actually when I replace the entire directory, it can no longer find proguard-android.txt

Comment: Please be aware that upgrading your SDK to a greater version (via the SDK manager) will reset your `tools` directory and, therefore, reset your proguard version to the one Android uses (version 4.7 from July 2011 is shipped with API 19)

Answer (score 9):

For the visually inclined, the version of Proguard can also be checked by double clicking on proguardgui.jar in ...\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib

Answer (score 1):

Quoting my own answer from over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787001/1127485), you can override the ProGuard version like so:

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.2'
        }
    }
}
```