# Proguard exception while creating release android apk

Tags: android, macos, apk, proguard, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am building an app engine connected android project using the eclipse plugin. The project is working fine and so I decide it's time to create a release APK. Using eclipse, I go through the process. But when I reached the end, I get an exception: `Proguard returned with error code 1`. I include the entire log below.

My GEP generated project comes with two proguard related files: `proguard-google-api-client.txt` and `proguard-project.txt`. There is also a project named proguard but it's empty. The `project.properties` file has two lines in it

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt
target=android-17
```

Will someone please help. Other than these proguard errors my code is working fine. I test in emulators and real devices. That never paused a problem in development. Also my backend is already deployed on app engine and I have no trouble using it with my dev api.

After some reading, I landed on [How can I check/upgrade Proguard version whn using it in Eclipse for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013163/how-can-i-check-upgrade-proguard-version-whn-using-it-in-eclipse-for-android-dev). But after I manually update proguard from 4.7 to 4.9, when I try to export an apk I get the eclipse error that it cannot find the file `android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`.

EDIT: Based on feedback I receive, I created the following file called `proguard-mine.txt`

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /projects/tools/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-8/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# -dontwarn android.support.**

# -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# -dontwarn com.google.common.cache.**

# -dontwarn com.google.common.primitives.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage.**

# -dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage.**
```

And then edited `project.properties` as

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt:proguard-mine.txt
```

But after the run, I still get the errors. Will someone please give me a hint on what my file is missing? I get the errors if I remove the `#` as well.

ERROR LOG:

```
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Note: there were 365 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
…
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: there were 199 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-05-01 14:22:25 - FriendsGame]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: After some more reading, I replaced with `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` but then eclipse says it cannot find `proguard.cfg` in my project directory, which of course it is not there. Am I supposed to create one manually?

Comment: of course you should create it manually. Take a look a t [this][1] proguard file example on sector 7. [1]: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication

Comment: @yugidroid Thanks for the link, See my edit above in response to what I find there.

Comment: Do you have any library jar? If so you have to declare them on the proguard file too... And I think you should create your proguard file on the main project's directory, thus you could define on properties the file exactly as you did on your first comment, IMO, is simpler than defining a long path tho the proguard config file.

Comment: As explained in the ProGuard documentation that yugidroid mentions, you should only specify such a long configuration if you create a build process from scratch. If you build from Ant or Eclipse, you should only enable ProGuard and perhaps add some minimal extra settings in proguard-project.txt. The build processes of Ant and Eclipse already specify standard settings, input jars, output jars, and library jars. If you specify them again you'll get lots of warnings about duplicate classes. For solving the actual problem: the Ant build provides more useful logging output than the Eclipse build.

Comment: I have just used `proguard` first time on yesterday.
I also got same error but i have added all the libraries in `proguard-mine.txt` which are in libs folder using `-libraryjars`.

Answer (score 1):

I have created my **`proguard-project.txt`**

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/gson-2.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/guava-11.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
-libraryjars /libs/protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
-libraryjars /libs/maps.jar

# Add any project specific keep options here:

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Check Library name with this all

edit **`project.properties`**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

May this one Helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: The Android Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes already automatically provide the proper -injars and -libraryjars options. You *must not* provide them again, or you will see many warnings about duplicate classes.

Comment: before it provided, i got warning, after that not.