# How to upgrade ProGuard for Android?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I used `Android SDK Manager` to download the latest version of Android SDK. But `ProGuard` was not updated and remained at version 4.7.

Is it necessary to manually download `ProGuard` from its [website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/) and unzip it to `\android-sdk\tools\proguard` ?

Or will Android SDK always use Version 4.7? It has been this way for [4 years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023215/7351137).

Comment: What features to do need that you don't already have?

Comment: In order to compile with Android Target SDK 24+, Java version 1.8 is required. But Java 1.8 is incompatible with Proguard 4.7.

Comment: Then how are developers compiling and still releasing their code? Did you enable the Jack compiler?

Comment: It is possible to export APK if all target SDK's are set to Android 6.0 (api23). I don't know what Jack compiler is.

Comment: You have to enable Jack compilation to even use the Java 8 featureset... https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: And this was posted about Proguard 3 years ago. https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/the_upcoming_jack_and_jill_compilers_in_android

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use Jack with Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe... it's just a Gradle setting... Eclipse can use Gradle... I wouldn't know, though, I haven't developed Android on Eclipse in three years because it's been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: Am I correct in inferring from this that current Android Studio cannot (without installing third party tools) generate signed apks when target is set to current Android? Isn't that rather strange?

Answer (score 54):

These days ProGuard is a dependency of the Android Gradle plugin, and is usually updated along with it. Looking at the output of `./gradlew buildEnvironment` (supported since [Gradle 2.10](https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/release-notes.html#new-task-for-visualising-a-buildscript-dependencies)) you will see something like

```
classpath
+--- com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3
|    \--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3
...
|         +--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1
|         |    \--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.2.1
```

If you want to use another ProGuard version than the one the Android Gradle plugin depends on you can override it like

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // We want version 5.3.2 instead of 5.2.1.
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.2'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Modify your `build.gradle` like so:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1' // <-- Add this line
        ...
    }
}
```

You don't have to manually download it.

Comment: This helped when I was getting a Unity Android build error (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10))

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a force resolution strategy to upgrade Proguard.
Instead declare the dependency in the Top-level ***build.gradle*** file such as -

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1'
    }
}
```